# #include <iostream> error in visual studio code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include-path

Not sure why because it worked fine before but I get an error when trying to include  in Visual Studio Code
[image]

I did add the include path to the properties.json file as in the picture but it's still not working
did i include the wrong path or is there any other solution?

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:\\MinGW",
                "C:\\MinGW\\include",
                "C:\\MinGW\bin",
                "C:\\MinGW\\lib"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: When you mention the `properties.json` file, do you really mean the `c_cpp_properties.json` file? And have you check e.g. [this MinGW on Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) documentation?

Comment: yes sorry, meant the c_cpp_properties.json file

Comment: and yes i checked the documentation and input/output worked just fine a few days ago and didnt change anything so I really dont know why i cant seem to include the standard library anymore

Comment: Add a prtscr of the MinGW/include dir please. I assume you selected Win32 as active in VC, correct?